# Python Watchdog error when files are downloaded from FTP

Tags: python, io, ftp, subprocess, python-watchdog

I'm using **Watchdog** to watch a directory for new **.xml** files being downloaded via **ftplib** on a time interval. When Watchdog see the file, **on_created()** triggers a function to process/parse the xml, but it seems that the file download hasn't completed yet causing an missing data error in the subsequent function.

I've added a **time.sleep(1)** before function is called which has alleviated the error, but adding a delay seems like an unreliable method in the real world. I'm wondering if there's a method similar to a **promise** function I can use vs. a delay. Or maybe I've completely misdiagnosed the issue and there's a simple answer? Open to any suggestion.

FYI... the files sizes can vary from roughly 100K to 4-5mg.

### **FTP Function**

```python
def download(f):
    ftpt = ftplib.FTP(server)
    ftpt.login(username, password)
    ftpt.cwd(ftp_dir)
    print 'Connected to FTP directory'
    if f.startswith('TLC-EMAILUPDATE'):
        if os.path.exists(dl_dir + f) == 0:
            fhandle = open(os.path.join(dl_dir, f), 'wb')
            print 'Getting ' + f
            ftpt.retrbinary('RETR ' + f, fhandle.write)
            fhandle.close()
        elif os.path.exists(dl_dir + f) == 1:
            print 'File', f, 'Already Exists, Skipping Download'


ftp = ftplib.FTP(server)
ftp.login(username, password)
ftp.cwd(ftp_dir)
infiles = ftp.nlst()

pool = Pool(4)
pool.map(download, in files)
```

### **Watchdog**

```python
def on_created(self, event):
    self.processfile(event)
    base = os.path.basename(event.src_path)
    if base.startswith('TLC-EMAILUPDATE'):
        print 'File for load report has been flagged'
        xmldoc = event.src_path
        if os.path.isfile(xmldoc) == 1:
            print 'File download complete'
            send_email(xmldoc)
```

### **Send Mail (with sleep)**

The exception is thrown at the **content** variable where the parsing fails to read any data from the downloaded file.

```python
def send_email(xmldoc):
    time.sleep(2)
    content = str(parse_xml.create_template(xmldoc))
    msg = MIMEText(content, TEXT_SUBTYPE)
    msg['Subject'] = EMAIL_SUBJECT
    msg['From'] = EMAIL_SENDER
    msg['To'] = listToStr(EMAIL_RECEIVERS)

    try:
        smtpObj = SMTP(GMAIL_SMTP, GMAIL_SMTP_PORT)
        smtpObj.ehlo()
        smtpObj.starttls()
        smtpObj.ehlo()
        smtpObj.login(user=EMAIL_SENDER, password=EMAIL_PASS)
        smtpObj.sendmail(EMAIL_SENDER, EMAIL_RECEIVERS, msg.as_string())
        smtpObj.quit()
        print 'Email has been sent to %s' % EMAIL_RECEIVERS
    except SMTPException as error:
        print 'Error: unable to send email : {err}'.format(err=error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: switch to monitoring the `CLOSE_WRITE` event.  Alas [Watchdog](http://pythonhosted.org//watchdog/api.html#watchdog.events.FileSystemEvent) doesn't support it directly.  Either:

1) switch to [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify) and use the following code -- Linux only, not OSX

2) use Watchdog with `on_any_event()`

### pyinotify example source

```
import os, sys

import pyinotify

class VideoComplete(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def process_IN_CLOSE_WRITE(self, event):
        sys.stdout.write(
            'video complete: {}\n'.format(event.pathname)
        )
        sys.stdout.flush()

def main():
    wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
    notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(
        wm, default_proc_fun=VideoComplete(),
        )
    mask = pyinotify.ALL_EVENTS
    path = os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads/incoming')
    wm.add_watch(path, mask, rec=True, auto_add=True)
    notifier.loop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

### download a file

```
echo beer > ~/Downloads/incoming/beer.txt
```

### output

```
video complete: /home/johnm/Downloads/incoming/beer.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! Pyinotify and OSX don't play we'll together in the sandbox. Going to load up on a linux box and I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: @jp_inc: oh, sorry about that. Yes, let me know what you find!